# Change FQDN of domain controller (and other hosts)

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Is there a way to change the fqdn of my Active Directory domain controller and other hosts in the domain?

Currently, my domain controller is called dc1.domain.com, and I'd like it to be dc1.site1.domain.com. Similarly, I have an web server called webserver1.domain.com, and I'd like it to be webserver1.site2.domain.com

I know I can just add a cname in the dns, but is there any way to make the actual FQDN modified to include the site?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  What real benefit to expect to achieve by changing the domain / suffix of your servers that cannot otherwise be achieved by including the site in the hostname, or by organzing your OU structure to align by location (which actually, I do not prefer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the FQDN of a domain controller by performing a domain rename operation.  That is the *only* option.

You can only change the FQDN of member servers by changing either 1) renaming the domain, or 2) changing the domain to which the sever belongs.

I recommend *against* hard-coding a location into the domain name.

If you do proceed with a domain rename (assuming you can - which you cannot do if Exchange is installed), I would recommend using a subdomain of a publicly registered domain (in your case **ad.domain.com**)

---

Failing these, you are left with resulting to DNS trickery, which you have already discovered - and (without *further* manipulation and unnecessary complication) will break any Kerberos-based authentication.

Comment: I should have been clearer, but this is for a new domain being created from scratch. I'd like the domain to be domain.com but have host names be host1.site1.domain.com

Comment: It doesn't really change anything at all, the FQDN of a server is exactly (and always) <hostname>.<domain>.  So unless you have additional domains, you will NEVER have <anything>.site1.domain.com as a server's FQDN.

Comment: Okay, understood. I hadn't realized that was the case since I've seen places with host names like server1.usa.domain.com and server2.europe.domain.com. But if what you're saying is true, then maybe those are just 2 separate domains which I didn't realize.